# Align Hebrew text right to left in a script on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hebrew

I found on this forum a very useful script for sending emails from Google Sheets. But, unfortunately, when I send the emails, the message is in Hebrew and is written from left to right (instead of right to left).

In CSS, there is an "rtl" option. But in Javascript, I didn't found anything similar.

The script and the screenshot of the email are below. I appreciate your help.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'קוד מוצר לרישיון שרכשת';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
```

[Hebrew text aligned left to right instead of right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWpI3.jpg)

Comment: You might want to fix your tags under your question. You have put `Excel` down.

Comment: You meant to say Hebrew is aligned right to left and your email is aligning it left to right correct? When you sent an email in gmail normally is it working the way you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the body as [htmlBody](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) instead using the `text-align` CSS property:

```
function example() {

  var htmlbody = '<html><head><style>.text{text-align: right;}</style></head><body><div class="text">body of your email</div></body></html>';

  MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress, subject:subject, htmlBody:htmlbody});

}
```